# Can we Use HTTP cache Manager for REST API Load runs

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am New to JMeter

I got a set of REST APIs that will run based on the Certificate authentication and I have got only 5 certificates and need to load run for 100 concurrent Users I am looping the certificates which I have. My question is can we use 'HTTP cache manager' for API runs and select 'Clear Cache each iteration' so that every time it runs I want to make sure that it doesn't get a response from the cache.

And how can I check if the APIs are hitting the servers every time and not getting the results from the cache

Answer (score 1):

No.

HTTP Cache Manager is about simulating **client** cache, for example if you open a "heavy" web page with tons of images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. JMeter (which [should act like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)) downloads these resources along with the main content.

The idea of the HTTP Cache Manager is to simulate **browser** cache as real browsers don't download these images, styles, etc. each time they access the page, they do it only once (or according to [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers), on subsequent requests the resources are being returned from the browser cache. See [HTTP Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) article for more details

Given you're testing an API it means that you're getting JSON or XML, no images, scripts, styles, fonts are being downloaded therefore it doesn't make sense even to add the HTTP Cache Manager.

If your application **caches the responses on server side** - the only workaround I can think of is to Parameterize/[Variabilize](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) your requests as if all your 100 virtual users will be sending the same request most likely your **server** will cache it somewhere somehow and subsequent responses will be much faster so make sure to generate more or less different requests to avoid hitting this server-side cache.

Comment: Thank You for your information. we will try to refresh the server cache every 10 seconds and use a timer element while sending requets